# In a datawarehouse can a dimension be related to another dimension?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, data-warehouse

I am currently developing a Data Warehouse and I was wondering if it makes sense to have a dimension connected to another via a foreign key.

For example, let's say we have two dimensions 'Country' and 'City' should we store only the City Dimension Key in the fact table. And the City is aware of it's Country.

Or does it make more sense two store both foreign keys in the fact table.

But the City dimension will have to know which Country it belongs to (it looks like it defies the star schema, since we now also have links between dimensions)

Or is this purely a design choice and will have no impact in querying, etc?

Comment: This is known as a "snowflake schema". Do whatever satisfies your business requirements.  If for exampke you had fact table that only went down to Country, then you need a Country dimension. However even in this case I would still endeavour to keep Country in the same dim as City, just for join simplicity.

Comment: When you say "keep Country in the same dim as City" does it mean to have only one table for them? Then we would have a record with the City column NULL to identify a country? (in case the fact table only goes down to Country)

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have relationship between your dimension tables. It can be a hierarchy too. Like product and product category. 
You can refer to snowflake schema design to know more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a straight answerm but consider these two scenarios;

### A. You have one fact table at the grain of city

- You may choose to have a star schema, which is

  - A single dimension containing city
  - This dimension contains a country column (which is repeated)

`factTransactionA >- dimCity`

- Or you may choose to have a snowflake schema, which is

  - A city dimension table
  - a seperate country dimension table
  - these dimensions can be joined.

`factTransactionA  >- dimCity >- dimCountry`

Both are valid but consider....

### B. You have one fact table at the grain of city and another one at the grain of country

When you're not sure of a design decision.... look for other constraints or requirements that help you make a decision

For case B you *have* to have a Country dimension. You shouldn't for example "overload" the city dimension and try to make it fit a fact table at the grain of Country. So you know you must have this:

`factTransactionB >- Country dimension table`

So if I extend this explanation on the fly.... typically, you use "conformed" dimensions between fact tables, so when we consider both fact tables, I would actually suggest this type of schema:

`factTransaction2 >- dimCountry  -< factTransaction1 >- dimCity`

Rather than this

`factTransaction2 >- dimCountry -< dimCity -< factTransaction1`

This actually means baking the dimCountry surrogate key into `factTransaction1` which is actually at City level.

Because

- My gut feel tells me we should avoid two conformed dimensions between facts
- If you have one fact at Country dimension, then Country is probably important enough in your business to bake into other facts to make it easy to compare metrics across facts.

So I feel in this long winded explanation I have posed one reason to avoid snowflake schemas, but they are definitely valid

Comment: I think we will go with the star schema, because we believe there can be use cases where we will need a fact table at the grain of country. Thanks a lot for the awesome explanation!